# Angular, when login then change apiUrl

Tags: angular

I stored apiUrl in app.config.ts like this

```
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('app.config');

export const AppConfig: any = {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
};
```

Then I used it in several services like these

```
projectPath = AppConfig.apiUrl + '/project';
supportPath = AppConfig.apiUrl + '/support';
paymentPath = AppConfig.apiUrl + '/payment';
```

But I want to update apiUrl when user logged in and update it default when logout.

If user logged in apiUrl should be

```
apiUrl = apiUrl + "/user"
```

I tried to check by using if else for each request individually. But I am looking for a better solution because I use projectsPath variable in many places.

My login and logout functions

```
export class UserService {
  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public user: Observable<User>;

  userPath = AppConfig.apiUrl + '/user';

  constructor(private router: Router,private http: HttpClient) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get userValue(): User {
    return this.userSubject.value;
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.userPath}/login`, {email, password})
      .pipe(map(user => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        return user;
      }));
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.userSubject.next(null);
    this.router.navigate([RoutesConfig.routes.login]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function in your common service or any service like

```
// import AppConfig;
updateBasePath() {
   if (localStorage.getItem('user')) { // your check for login
      AppConfig.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/user';
   } else {
      AppConfig.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
   }
}
```

Call this function after login and logout success.

Or

```
updateBasePath() {
   if (localStorage.getItem('user')) { // your check for login
      if (AppConfig.apiUrl.indexOf('/user') === -1) {
          AppConfig.apiUrl = AppConfig.apiUrl + '/user';
      }
   } else {
      if (AppConfig.apiUrl.indexOf('/user') > -1) {
          AppConfig.apiUrl = AppConfig.apiUrl.replace('/user', '');
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask something about this solution. If the user logs in and closes the browser, it does not log out. When the browser is opened again, it continues as logged in. In this case, since the login or logout functions will not be called again, the updateBasePath () function will not be called too. Is this a problem? If so how can I solve this problem.

Comment: @HakanEryücel you can call this function, in constructor of service. So that each time app initializes your url will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a  new method in your service project.service.ts   and after successful login call that method to update projectPath variable with new end point. On logout reset it to previous value.

Comment: I misrepresented what I wanted. I updated my question. I want to update apiUrl rather than projectsPath. Because I use it in more than one service and this update should be for all services.

Comment: First thing I would like to suggest that you should build a common service for making api calls. For example if its name is api.service.ts. It should have all http methods you wish to call i.e (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc) and then from other services you should call any of these methods as per the requirement. If it was done like this you shouldn't have to worry about making changes in a lot of places.  Second i would say Kenny's solution is fine but it is not a good idea to update values of a constant.

Comment: Other solution could be

1. Add a new key in AppConfig like this:  export const AppConfig: any = {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000', 
  apiUrlAfterLogin: 'http://localhost:3000/user'
};

2. On login set urlKey="apiUrlAfterLogin" in local storage.

3. On logout set urlKey="apiKey" in local storage

4. Now in whole app find and replace AppConfig.apiUrl with AppConfig[localStorage.getItem['urlKey']]

I believe it should work.